# how to get selected item from ListView on Java, Android

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView with adapter:

```
ListView names=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);

String[] items=new String[mMusicData.size()];
mMusicData.keySet().toArray(items);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});
names.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And when I try to get id of selected item in other function I always got -1:

```
Log.e("1", String.valueOf(names.getSelectedItemPosition()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
names.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //use POSITION to get item clicked
        }
    });
```